# Can I automatically update the file generated by generate:doctrine:crud with another command?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I juste want to know if I can achieve this :

I used the `generate:doctrine:crud` to CRUD my entity and I can't figure how to simply regenerate the CRUD files without delete them. Is there a way to achieve this ?

I looked on the big internet but found nothing. Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not how the crudgen works.

However, there is not much reason to engage as you've said, because the default crud generator files are very small, and will look the same before and after regeneration (unless you've made customizations to your skeletons).

If you really need this behavior write a bash script (or windows equivalent) to delete the files before regenerating, but, again, you won't need to do this unless you've got a custom skeleton.

(Note in edit: If you are trying to convert varying formats -- annotations to yml, you'll want to delete the files anyhow).